# Javascript regex or other parsing technique to extract the contents of last set of parentheses in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract the rightmost parenthetical (the last one) from a string that has 1-N parentheticals.

For example, in  `Some title (8888)(123, bar)(1000, foo)`  I want to get the contents of the last set of parentheses, i.e. `1000, foo`.  There will always be at least one parenthetical, but may be more than one.

I am fine with using regex, or other string parsing techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they are not nested you can simply do: `/\(([^\)]+)\)$/`

```
var foo = "Some title (8888)(123, bar)(1000, foo)";
// Get your result with
foo.match(/\(([^\)]+)\)$/)[1];
```

Demonstration: http://regex101.com/r/tS2yS1

Answer (score 1):

[follow this link](http://regexr.com?35lar)

you will see with that regex `.*\((.+)\)` you can get $1(group one) as your wanted content

Answer (score 0):

Match all parentheticals, and get the last one.

```js
> 'Some title (8888)(123, bar)(1000, foo)'.match(/\(.*?\)/g).pop()
"(1000, foo)"

> var x = 'Some title (8888)(123, bar)(1000, foo)'.match(/\(.*?\)/g).pop(); x.substr(1, x.length-2)
"1000, foo"
```